# Nested dict keys as variable

Tags: python

There must be a more graceful way of doing this but I cannot figure out how to create a single function for reading/writing values to different levels of a dict, this is the 'best' that I could come up with:

```
table = {
    'A': {
        'B': '2',
        'C': {
            'D':'3'
        }
    }
}
first = 'A'
second1 = 'B'
second2 = 'C'
third = 'D'

def oneLevelDict(first):
    x = table[first]
    print(x)

def twoLevelDict(first, second):
    x = table[first][second]
    print(x)

def threeLevelDict(first, second, third):
    x = table[first][second][third]
    print(x)

oneLevelDict(first)
twoLevelDict(first, second1)
threeLevelDict(first, second2, third)
```

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but related to an extent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: @TrebuchetMS, both questions are about dictionaries, but this question is specifically about how to get access to a value at an arbitrary level of a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *args to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to a function. You can then use a loop to traverse the levels.

```
get_any_level(*keys):
    d = table
    for key in keys:
        d = d[key]
    return d
```

Now you have one function that can replace the three you had before:

```
print(get_any_level(first))
print(get_any_level(first, second1))
print(get_any_level(first, second2, third))
```

You can use this function to write to an arbitrary level as well:

```
get_any_level(first)[second1] = 17
```

A better way might be to have a separate function to write though:

```
def put_any_level(value, *keys):
    get_any_level(*keys[:-1])[keys[-1]] = value

put_any_level(17, first, second1)
```

`value` has to come first in the argument list unless you want it to be keyword-only because `*keys` will consume all positional arguments. This is not necessarily a bad alternative:

```
def put_any_level(*keys, value):
    get_any_level(*keys[:-1])[keys[-1]] = value
```

The keyword argument adds clarity:

```
put_any_level(first, second1, value=17)
```

But it will also lead to an error if you attempt to pass it as a positional argument, e.g. `put_any_level(first, second1, 17)`.

Couple of minor points:

1. It's conventional to use CamelCase only for class names. Variables and functions are conventionally written in lowercase_with_underscores.
2. A function should generally do one thing, and do it well. In this case, I've split the task of finding the nested value from the task of displaying it by giving the function a return value.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: @Aditya. I appreciate you saying that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - thank you for explaining this. *args was the key! Appreciate the convention tips also - new language - new conventions.

Comment: @MattYYC glad you liked it. You can select the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using *args. Read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/)

And this is how to do it:

```
def allLevelDict(*argv):
  if len(argv) == 1:
    x  = table[argv[0]]
    print (x)
  elif len(argv) == 2:
    x  = table[argv[0]][argv[1]]
    print (x)
  elif len(argv) == 3:
    x  = table[argv[0]][argv[1]][argv[2]]
    print (x)
allLevelDict(first)
allLevelDict(first, second1)
allLevelDict(first, second2, third)
```

Comment: By `x  = table[first]` did you mean `x  = table[argv[0]]`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Changed it now.Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @AdityaK! [This](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/) was also a good explanation on *args

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other suggestions, but perhaps even more graceful, if you like recursion:

```
table = {'A':{'B':'2','C':{'D':'3'}}}
first = 'A'
second1 = 'B'
second2 = 'C'
third = 'D'


def get_from(x, *keys):
    return get_from(x[keys[0]], *keys[1:]) if len(keys) > 0 else x


print(get_from(table, first))
print(get_from(table, first, second1))
print(get_from(table, first, second2, third))
```

Note: I'm also passing in the table, since I imagine you'd want to be able to use it on other dictionaries also.

Or, if you think shorter isn't always better:

```
def get_from(x, *keys):
    if len(keys) > 0 
        return get_from(x[keys[0]], *keys[1:])
    else:
        return x
```

Normally, recursion can be dangerous, as it's expensive - but since you're unlikely to have incredibly deep dictionaries, I feel it is the right solution here.

Comment: Thanks @Grismar - very succinct.  Is the [1:] equivalent to a popitems()? Not sure what this means.

Comment: `[1:]` means 'all elements from the sequence, starting with the element at index 1'. So, for `x = [1,2,3,4]`, `x[1:]` would be `[2,3,4]` - read more here on this, called 'slicing' https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

It's not equivalent to `popitem()`, not just because it returns a larger part of the sequence, but also more importantly because it does not modify the original - it returns a copy of its contents.